# For compact Hausdorff space $X$, prove that $X\setminus\{x_0\}$ is locally compact.

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to prove the thing in the title.
Maybe this has been asked before, but I can't seem to find the specific question.

Comment: Try starting with $X=[0,1]$ and prove it in that case. Then try to generalize your proof.

Comment: Choose any point $x\neq x_0$, let $U, V$ be disjoint neighbourhoods of $x$ and $x_0$, respectively. Then check if the closure of $U$ is compact.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in X$ since $X$ is Hausdorff, there exist neighborhood $U,V$ such that $x_0\in U, x\in V$ and $U\cap V$ is empty.

Let show that the closure $\bar V$ of $V$ is compact and contained in $X-\{x_0\}$, let $(y_n)$ a sequence $y_n\in\bar V$ since $X$ is compact there exists a subsequence $y_{n_k}, limy_{n_k}=y$. Suppose $y=x_0$, there exists $N$ such that $n_k>N$ implies that $y_{n_k}\in U$. Fix an $n_k>N$ since $y_{n_k}\in \bar V$, there exists $z_p, z_p\in V, lim z_p=y_{n_k}$, since $y_{n_k}\in U, n_k>N$, there exists $M$ such that $p>M$ implies $z_p\in U$ contradiction since $z_p\in V$ and $U\cap V$ is empty.

Edit: you can replace the word sequence here by net.

Comment: sequences don't suffice in general.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is compact Hausdorff (so normal, and regular) and $O \subseteq X$ is open. If $x \in O$ then there is an open set $U$ of $X$ such that $x \in U \subseteq \overline{U} \subseteq O$, by regularity of $X$ and $U$ is open in $O$ too and its closure is compact (being closed in $X$). So $O$ is locally compact.

Finally note that $O=X\setminus \{x_0\}$ is open (Hausdorff implies $T_1$).